# apache not serving images in img tags but i can access them directly through the URL

Tags: php, image, google-chrome, ubuntu, apache2

ok, I just set up a new EC2 instance and everything is running ok, except for images don't seem to want to load. The html, js, and css all load quickly and then the browser spins waiting for images. Chrome says the request is pending and I never get any response headers back. I can access the images directly through Chrome so this isn't a permissions issue I don't think. I have a self signed SSL for development -- could that be the cause? The site doesn't even load in firefox... but in chrome i get all but images.

Webpage with images not loading:
https://socialshoppro.com

Image that should be loaded on the page:
https://socialshoppro.com/images/logo2.png

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: works for me on debian 6 chrome 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is probably blocking it because of SSL certificate isn't valid.

Comment: fair enough, but i am able to load the site on my local vm in firefox with a snakeoil certificate (also not valid)

Comment: It's working for me. I see all images. It may be a DNS issue on your end. http://tinypic.com/r/2vc94pj/5